# PL/pgSQL function to count rows in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a function in PL/pgSQL which will count the number of rows in a table `simulated_records` where the school name is "CAA". I want to save this number in a variable called `count` and then return it. However, I keep getting an error on or near 'SELECT'.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grades()returns integer AS $$
DECLARE 
count integer; --counts total number per school
BEGIN
count := SELECT count(school) FROM simulated_records WHERE school ='CAA';
return count;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: `plsql` is the procedural language of Oracle, I fixed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use [`SELECT INTO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) or enclose the subselect in parentheses:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grades()
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
DECLARE 
count integer; --counts total number per school
BEGIN
count := (SELECT count(school)::int FROM simulated_records WHERE school ='CAA');
return count;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Also note that `count()` returns `bigint` which can lead to a type mismatch, so I added a cast.

The example is pretty noisy, though. Just use query directly, or use a simpler sql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grades()
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
SELECT count(school)::int FROM simulated_records WHERE school ='CAA';
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

And if `school` is defined `NOT NULL` then use `count(*)`.